# Using Laravel Storage Facade to access files on another PC

Tags: laravel, file, storage, facade, laravel-facade

So , there's a machine where i have some files, and i would like to access those files from my Laravel project that is running locally.

This machine is on an example host like 10.0.101.11 , how can i access this with my laravel project?

My filesystem.php disks

```
'disks' => [

        'ftp' => [
            'driver'   => 'ftp',
            'host'     => '10.0.101.11',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'passwd',
            'root'     => 'C:/',
            'port'     => 11,
        ],
        'root' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => 'D:/'
        ],
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
]
```

My local machine and the host are in the same network, is there anyway i can access it's directories without using ftp?

Comment: My first thought would be to mount the target folder in advance, and access it "locally". FTP should work too. Both though, are more a question of getting the host machine to allow its content to be accessible, rather than focus your efforts on the Laravel configuration yet. I'd recommend starting by experimenting with FTP access from a command terminal just to verify that's working first, before adding an app to the mix. For the moment though, is there any kind of error message you're getting back on how you have things set up already?

Comment: The only error message returned is could not connect to Host on Port , but in cmd if i run ping Host i get a response, what made me think that the connection was fine